# Is a valve stem and valve guide oil seal replacement on my 4.0 Ford possible?

Tags: ford

Is a Valve stem and valve guide OIL SEAL replacement on my 4.0 Liter ford possible? Would (plenty of Hot) compressed Air be helpful to have for this process. My brother (aspiring genius mechanic) says he and his compressor will stick around if he is correct about the valve seals being replaceable

Comment: I would be surprised if it wasn't possible to replace the oil seals.  Why do you think hot compressed air would be useful?

Comment: If you are going to replace the oil seals, it would be a good idea to perform a compression test first to check if your valves are sealing properly.  If they are not closing properly due to a build up of burnt oil on the back of them, then more work may be required.

Comment: Valve stem oil seals and valve seats  are totally different . First decide which one , or both, need work.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be misstating what you are intending to do. I don't think you really want to replace the valve stem, as this would require replacing the entire valve, which would incur you needed to pull the head to accomplish.

If you are looking to just replace the valve seals, you will need an on head valve spring compressor. Here is one example (there are other types):

[image]

If you go this route, the compressed air (whether hot or not) can help, but you'll need an adapter which will thread into your spark plug hole. The idea is to put pressure into the cylinder to keep the valves up while you pull the springs off. An example might look like this:

[image]

To use this adapter, turn the piston of the cylinder you're working on to top dead center (TDC), then apply air.

If this kind of procedure is for you, then, yes, the compressed air will help you out. If it's not something you're willing to do, then you may want to leave it for a professional.

Comment: @Jsanb - This *should* answer your question. If not, please clarify. If you are looking for further light and knowledge on exactly what to do to change out a valve seal using this method, please post it in a separate question and I'd be happy to give you instructions.

Comment: The "rope trick" is another way to keep the valves closed. Remove spark plug. Rotate engine so the piston is at the bottom. Stuff some rope into the cylinder through the plug hole (a bamboo chopstick is useful for pushing it in). Rotate the piston to TDC, or as close as you can get; the rope will be pressed against the valves, and keep them closed.

Comment: @MikeBaranczak - Two things: 1) yes it will work, but it's a true PITB. Compressed air is *soooo* much easier to use; 2) the OP was asking about compressed air.

Comment: Thanx, the method Paulster2 mentioned  makes sense for this situation and yes a detailed description would be very appreciated. also is there any thoughts regarding the adding of a cleanable vacuum CAN at the PCV location? I have seen some for sale or we could make one (Ideas?). and where is the best position for it? before the PCV or directly after it? Do i need to post these Q's as seperate new questions?

Comment: Yes, please post these as different/separate questions :D If you believe my post has answered your question, please consider checking the checkmark below the voting buttons to show it has succeeded in doing so.